# How to store a matrix permanently through matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, hard-drive

In matlab I am getting a matrix of MxN size, I need to store this in secondary storage for retrieval in future. How I can store a matrix permanently and how it's possible to read into a variable.

Comment: This is a very simple question. Did you even searched online? If you put `save matrix matlab` in google, the first link is the answer. C'mon...

Answer (score -1):

Say your matrix is `m`. Save it to a file:

```
save myfile.mat m
```

You can save it as ascii:

```
save('myfile.txt','m','-ascii')
```

or as `save -ascii myfile.txt m`.

You can see the contents of this file:

```
type('myfile.txt')
```

You can load all the contents of your `mat` file:

```
load myfile.mat
```

or a specific variable:

```
load('myfile.mat','m')
```

or simply `load myfile.mat m`.  Similarly load your data from the ascii file:

```
load myfile.txt -ascii
```

Once you have loaded the data from the `mat`or `ascii` files you have the matrix `m` and you can set it equal to any variable that you like.